# Vitrification of Humans for Later Revival

Tags: cryonics

In the video from Tom Scott "[I promise this story about microwaves is interesting.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2tdiKTSdE9Y)
" high success rate in multiple reanimations of a hamster was stated by scientist interviewee J. E. Lovelock who worked on these experiments. In the near end of the video the scientist says that it is not possible on larger organisms partially because you cannot get antifreeze agents to diffuse into the cells quickly enough. Searching on this topic I found out that antifreeze is required because if ice forms it expands and damages the cell walls and more. Although in how Lovelock was describing the experiments, it seemed as if they quickly cooled the hamster to between 0 and 1 degrees celcius, see "[Reanimation of rats from body temperatures between 0 and 1° C by microwave diathermy](https://physoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1113/jphysiol.1955.sp005323)" and "[Resuscitation of Hamsters after Supercooling or Partial Crystallization at Body Temperatures Below 0° C.](https://www.nature.com/articles/1731136a0)". From the original Nature article

> Hamsters, chosen because of their known adaptability to body temperatures between 2.5° and 38° C.,
> were cooled by the method recently described by
> Andjus and Smith for rats. After transfer to icy
> water, the deep body temperature was recorded from a
> colonic thermocouple connected to a potentiometer
> or a microvoltmeter recording with an accuracy of
> ±0.3 deg. C. In our experience the hamster ceases
> to respire at body temperatures between + 2.5° and + 6° C., and heart beats are no longer visible at +1.8 - 3.5° C.

it is then said that

> After cessation of
> respiration, the animal was transferred to a 50 per
> cent propylene glycol bath maintained at - 4 ° to - 7° C., which reduced body temperature to zero in
> 7-10 min. Under these conditions, some animals
> became supercooled so that body temperature might
> reach - 5·5° C. or even below in a further 50-70 min.

Propylene glycol being an ingredient in antifreeze also being non-toxic which is seen in its use as a food additive. Although nowhere in this method is it said that it somehow is administered into the hamster so that it can diffuse into the cells themselves. It is also said that an estimated 15% of total body water crystallized (froze/became ice). These hamsters were then successfully revived. Why does Lovelock then say that it does not work on humans because of antifreeze not diffusing fast enough? From searching around one reason is that it does not work because it is not possible to cool a human body quick enough, although if it became possible to vitrify a body quick enough and heat it up quick enough. Would it then become possible to revive humans and or bigger animals?

My main question is how and why does it matter how big the animal that is being frozen matter? What exactly makes it possible on hamsters and not on for example a dog or a human being? I understand that it takes significantly longer to cool a human being compared to a hamster. But I do not understand how for example the heart cells do not die in the process of cooling a hamster compared to a human. The cooling pattern is the same for both, and the heart in both cases will be deprived of blood therefore oxygen. The amount of expansion caused by potential ice formation will be the same on hamsters and humans because the size of the cells are roughly the same.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Kleiber's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleiber%27s_law)? Would it be a sufficient answer for you?

Answer (score -1):

I think you may be "assuming facts not in evidence" :)  You are focusing on the size of the animal. However, your quote notes, "Hamsters, chosen because of their known adaptability to body temperatures between 2.5° and 38° C., ", that is hamsters were chosen not for their size, but because they were known to be able to adapt to temperatures as cold as 2.5C.

Determining the mechanisms of how hamsters can adapt to such cold temperatures would certainly be interesting.